# Rails 3.0 rmagick Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I'm trying to install the rmagick gem for a rails 3.0 app and I run into the following error:

RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.

I've added the following code to my gem file:

```
  gem "rmagick", "~> 2.13.1"
```

After that I ran bundle install.

That's when the error occurs.

Now I've search on here and the interent, but have not found a solution to this problem.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you installed ImageMagick already? RMagick is just a wrapper for it.

Comment: Assuming you're on linux, this might help: http://superuser.com/questions/163818/how-to-install-rmagick-on-ubuntu-10-04

Comment: Nope, but I just installed it and got the same error after running bundle install.

Comment: I'm developing the app locally on a windows machine.